# Отправка фото на стену через VK Api wall.post

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пытаюсь отправить картинку на стену паблика (я создатель)
Фото на сервер ВК загрузил. Осталось только добавить его на стену при помощи wall.post. Делаю так (токен и версия vk api добавляется в функции getApiMethod):

```
    if($getUrl)   {
$postPhoto = getApiMethod('wall.post', array(
            'owner_id' => $publicID, //номер паблика с указанием минуса
            'from_group' => "0",
            'friends_only' => 0,
            'message' => "",
            'attachments' => "photo".$publicID."_".$photo_id, ));

   }
         setLog('Отправка фото на стену '.$postPhoto);
```

Получаю ошибку

```
{"error":{"error_code":100,"error_msg":"One of the parameters specified was missing or invalid: invalid message param","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"wall.post"},{"key":"attachments","value":"photo_456316165"},{"key":"friends_only","value":"0"},{"key":"from_group","value":"0"},{"key":"message","value":""},{"key":"owner_id","value":"-71257780"},{"key":"v","value":"5.63"}]}}
```

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в attachments нет owner_id, поэтому фото считается невалидным, а значит пустым, поэтому и требуется message

```
"key":"attachments","value":"photo_456316165"
```